# jquery filter from drop down

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how I would create an option to filter content based off of a drop down. I am not looking for a plugin, as long as this is not something that is difficult. here is an example of what I need to do when a selection is selected from drop down:

```
<select name="division-select" id="division-select">
 <option value="halter">Halter</option>
 <option value="english">English</option>
</select>

<div>
 <p class="halter">halter class 1</p>
 <p class="halter">halter class 2</p>
 <p class="english">english class 1</p>
 <p class="english">english class 2</p>
</div>
```

So what I would like to happen is when there is a select from the drop down box, the option that is selected would automatically hide any paragraphs that do not have the class that does not have the class that equals the option value.

Is this possible?

Thank you for any help on this.

Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#division-select").bind("change", function() {
    $("." + this.value).show();
    $("p:not(." + this.value + ")").hide();
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/KcStv/

**Notes:**

- Binds an event handler to the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event of the `select` element.
- Calls [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) on the element who's class is equal to that of the current value of the select (`this.value`).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)s the other `p` tags without that class using the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.

Comment: you still need to append a `.change()` at the end to trigger manually, or else it will display all `<p>` irrespective of the default selected

Comment: The OP does not mention hiding anything on page load, but yes that would accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#division-select').change(function() {
    var matches = $('div > p.' + $(this).val());
    matches.show().siblings().not(matches).hide();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/drBRf/).

If you want this to do its magic at load, chain `change()` after the event is attached to trigger it.

Comment: you should put a `.change()` event at the end to trigger it manually or else all `<p>` are displayed irrespective of their default selected  `http://jsfiddle.net/drBRf/1/`